# Заставить работать javascript в slim - шаблоне

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Сообственно, инструкция по установке фрейма (судя по синтаксису, скорее всего на пхп):

```
<p id="iframe-container" style="max-width: 800px;"></p>
```

Вставляется скрипт, содержащий объект Portmone, в `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.portmone.com.ua/r3/js/iframe/portmone.min.js?v=2110201615"></script>
```

Последним шагом нужно проинициализировать объект Portmone так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<!—
    if (typeof(Portmone) !== "undefined") {
        var portmone = new Portmone({
            lang: 'ru', 
            prefix: 'vodokanal', 
            service: 'terminal-item/10035', 
            container: 'iframe-container'
       });
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Скрипт инициализации желательно вставлять на страницу в секцию `body` непосредственно перед контейнером (именно туда, где и будет формироваться `IFRAME`).

Вопрос: как этот фрейм граммотно расписать и заставить работать в шаблоне slim?  Что куда писать? Буду благодарен за ответы с примерами.

Answer (score 0):

Из доки:
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frame
Попробуй:

```
javascript:
  alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!')
```